# php server can't find curl.so

Tags: php, curl, server, centos

I'm deploying PHP environment. And in my project, I use curl function so I also configure curl. But it fails.

### Running Environment

```
Server: Tencent Cloud Server  
Operating System: CentOS 7.2  
PHP version: 5.6
```

## location of curl.so file

https://segmentfault.com/img/bVbcnM2?w=668&h=141

## php.ini file

https://segmentfault.com/img/bVbcnM3?w=889&h=178

## location of php.ini

https://segmentfault.com/img/bVbcnM4?w=641&h=150

## phpinfo()

https://segmentfault.com/img/bVbcnM5?w=1190&h=888

## running result

https://segmentfault.com/img/bVbcnM8?w=1262&h=74

I'm so confused. Please help me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Did you install php5.6-curl extension？If you did then which manner you installed it? By yum install or from sources.And through the information the loaded php configure file is in

> usr/local/bin/php/lib/php.ini

Did you try move or copy a configure file to this directory? If not work ,try

> yum install php5.6-curl

Comment: Yes, I have installed from sources. I use phpize to generate curl.so file. And then, I add the path of this .so file into php.ini. I don't do any other things.

Comment: How about the php.ini file? Did you move to the loaded directory?